# How to determine that a jquery tab (idTabs) is ready and visible inside my javascript function?

Tags: jquery, idtabs

I created some tabs in my page using idTabs jquery plugin. There are couple of tables inside the tabs that getting rendered using ajax calls. Now I need to make the tables scrollable and I am trying to do that using jquery tableScroll widget. 
So my function for the scrolling needs to be called after the tab is ready and visible (because it need to read the height of table). How can I determine the situation of a tab? I mean is there any call back function for that? 
I tried document.ready and window.load but apparently I need to tell the function that the tab is ready and visible before call it. Can anybody help?

Comment: If you want to make a table scrollable why don't you just use `overflow:auto` in your css?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  create: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reference. Would it be the same for jquery idTabs?